# Google Apps Engine real time monitoring

Tags: google-app-engine, monitoring

I have a web app which are running on google apps engine, is there any way to have real time usage monitoring (like traffic, cpu, etc..), I know there is standard dashboard, but I want to have more details in one place. Like see whats IP are connected, how many requests each produces and etc.

So maybe anyone have some input on this ?

Answer (score 2):

[Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) will give you more indepth information about your requests with an aim to helping you optimise your rpc queries.

If you want to monitor how your users are interacting with your webapp then you should look at using something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics), [Mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com/) or [Kissmetrics](http://kissmetrics.com/)